# Redefinition of spacetime coordinates for Noether's Theorem

Tags: spacetime, symmetry, field-theory, coordinate-systems, noethers-theorem

In the derivation of Noether's theorem some authors consider not only redefinitions of the fields
\begin{equation}
\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x) = \phi(x) +\delta\phi(x)
\end{equation}
but also redefinitions of the spacetime coordinates
\begin{equation}
x^{\mu} \rightarrow x'^{\mu} = x^{\mu} +\delta x^{\mu} \ . \qquad(*)
\end{equation}
It is not quite clear to me what this redefinition of spacetime coordinates means.

Until now i have thought that it is just a switch in the coordinate system. I.e. if $P$ is a point in spacetime and we assign it the coordinate $x(P)$, usually a 4-vector, then we could just as well label it with the different coordinate $x'(P)$. Therefore $x$ and $x'$ describe the same point in spacetime.

When taking this point of view, however, i have run into some trouble in the derivation of Noether's theorem. I would like to know if my conception of the meaning of $(*)$ is correct or if not what the correct interpretation is.

My question is $\textbf{not a duplicate}$ of [Noether's theorem in classical field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174615/noethers-theorem-in-classical-field-theory) as that question does not address whether $x$ and $x'$ refer to the same point in spacetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Noether's theorem in classical field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174615/)

Comment: related: [Group representations and active/passive transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401629/84967) and links therein.

Comment: Whenever we talk about symmetries in QFT, the associated transformations act on fields, not coordinates. Sometimes, for example when dealing with spacetime transformations when deriving the energy-momentum tensor, you will come across transformations acting on coordinates. But that is done to use them as a crutch to, *finally*, be able to express transformations on *fields* only. See this answer, for instance: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/359199/133418

Comment: @Zarathustra You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The shift $\delta x^\mu=\epsilon^\mu$  is just a relabeling of the points of spacetime. After the relabelling the point $P$ that had coordinate $x^\mu$ now has coordinate $x^\mu- \epsilon^\mu$ and the point $P'$ that now has coordinate $x^\mu$ is  point $P+  \epsilon$.  The field at point $P$ is unchanged, but $\varphi(x^\mu)$ now refers to the field at $P+\epsilon$ and so
$$
\varphi(x^\mu)\mapsto \varphi(x^\mu +\epsilon^\mu) =\varphi(x) + \epsilon^\mu \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^\mu}+ O(\epsilon^2)  
$$
Similarly 
$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x)dx^\mu dx^\nu  \mapsto g_{\mu\nu}(x+\epsilon)d(x^\mu+\epsilon^\mu)d(x^\nu+
\epsilon^\nu)\\
= (g_{\mu\nu}(x) +\nabla_\mu \epsilon_\nu+\nabla_\nu\epsilon_\mu)dx^\mu dx^\nu
$$
where some covariant derivative identities are used at the lat step.

This relabeling cannot change anything physical, so, in particular, the action functional cannot  be changed by it.

Now, if the equations of motion are obeyed the action is unchanged by any  change in the fields. Combining these two facts, and an integration by parts  leads to 
$$
0=\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu},
$$
where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the Hilbert energy-momentum tensor defined by 
$$
\delta S = \frac 12 \int d^dx \sqrt{g}  T^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu}.
$$

Comment: this does not answer my question. Do x and x' refer to the same spacetime point? if two observers A and A' describe the world using $x, \phi$ and $x', \phi'$ respectively would they measure the field values during some event P to be $\phi(x(P))$ and $\phi`(x(P) + \epsilon)$ or not?

Comment: @Zarathustra. I'll edit my comment to be clearer.